# PHP Json array in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to catch Code=10720 in PHP .But I can't.Thanks.

```
{
    "OrderId":"6597943",
    "ExtOrderId":"ExtOrderId0",
    "MerchantPosId":"KAMPUSHG",
    "Status":{
        "StatusCode":"OPENPAYU_ERROR_VALUE_INVALID",
        "Code":"10720",
        "CodeLiteral":"TRANSACTION_INVALID_PARAMS",
        "Location":"InstallmentPayment",
        "StatusDesc":["INVALID_CARD_NO","INVALID_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE","INVALID_CARD_CVV"]
    }
}
```

Comment: `json_decode()` can help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '{
            "OrderId":"6597943",
            "ExtOrderId":"ExtOrderId0",
            "MerchantPosId":"KAMPUSHG",
            "Status":{
                "StatusCode":"OPENPAYU_ERROR_VALUE_INVALID",
                "Code":"10720",
                "CodeLiteral":"TRANSACTION_INVALID_PARAMS",
                "Location":"InstallmentPayment",
                "StatusDesc":["INVALID_CARD_NO"]
            }
         }';

$ar = json_decode($json,true); # json-string to array

# PHP Version < 7
$code = isset($ar['Status']['Code'])?$ar['Status']['Code']:'default value'; 

# PHP Version >= 7  
$code = isset($ar['Status']['Code'])??'default value';
```

Comment: When you use json_decode you must **notice** the second param and the fourth param:true to get array format,false to get object format : ）

Comment: Also notice the fourth param:if you want to get **big-int-string** you need **JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING** @see [default is to cast large integers as floats when use json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: _"You can be a pro in what you do, there will be always a 12 year old chinese kid better than you.."_ (joking)

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array = '{"OrderId":"6597943","ExtOrderId":"ExtOrderId0","MerchantPosId":"KAMPUSHG","Status":{"StatusCode":"OPENPAYU_ERROR_VALUE_INVALID","Code":"10720","CodeLiteral":"TRANSACTION_INVALID_PARAMS","Location":"InstallmentPayment","StatusDesc":["INVALID_CARD_NO","INVALID_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE","INVALID_CARD_CVV"]}}';


$decode = json_decode($array);
echo $decode->Status->Code; // Output 10720
```

And if you want an array instead of an object

```
$decode = json_decode($array, true);
echo $decode['Status']['Code']; // Output 10720
```